# 'this.props.tasks.map is not a function' error-React error

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

While passing the array to the component I am getting the error-'this.props.tasks.map is not a function'

My Main.js code

```
let posts = [
    {
        id: 1,
        description: "This is a task",
        status: "pending"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        description: "This is another task",
        status: "pending"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        description: "This is an easy task",
        status: "pending"

    }
];



class Main extends Component {
    render() {
        return <div>
            <Title title="Photowall" />
            <Photowall posts={ posts } />

        </div>
    }
}
```

and the Photowall.js code

```
 render() {
        return <div>
            {this.props.posts.map((item) => <Photo key={item} post={item}/>)}
             </div>

    }
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. Let me know if it's not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `posts` like below.

```
<Photowall posts={posts} />
```

**Photowall.js** 
You have to pass `key={item.id}` and I guess this will work.

```
 render() {
        return <div>
            {this.props.posts.map((item) => <Photo key={item.id} post={item}/>)}
             </div>

    }
```

**Photo**

```
class Photo extends Component { 
   render() { 
        const data = this.props.post; 
        return <p>{data.description}</p> 
    } 
}
```

If you are passing like `{{ posts }}` then it will be consider as below at other end.

```
{
   posts: [
    {
        id: 1,
        description: "This is a task",
        status: "pending"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        description: "This is another task",
        status: "pending"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        description: "This is an easy task",
        status: "pending"

    }
]
}
```

So that's why this will not work.

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: while passing this I am getting "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {ingredients}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." error

Comment: you have to update your render code like this. `{this.props.posts.map((item) => <Photo key={item.id} post={item}/>)}`. Let me know is it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to write

```
<Photowall posts={ posts } />
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are passing `Object of array` by passing `posts={{posts}}`.

Only pass this,

```
<Photowall posts={ posts } />
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-yztmwu)

Comment: while passing this I am getting "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {ingredients}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." error

Comment: Post yur `Photo ` component. In `Photo` component you might be printing object.

Comment: class Photo extends Component {
        render() {
            const data = this.props.item
            return <p>{data.description}</p>
        }
    }

Comment: This is wrong `data = this.props.item`, it should be `data = this.props.post`. Check the demo link.